# Dovecot cannot connect to MySQL

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, dovecot

I'm trying to configure dovecot on my server, and whenever I'm trying to connect, I'm getting this as  the response in the `/var/log/mail.log` file.

[image: Error cannot connect to database]

This is the line I have in the `/etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext` file that contains the connect line.

```
connect = host=127.0.0.1 dbname=servermail user=mailadmin password='pass#12@FQ'
```

Even though I'm specifying to connect to mysql via 127.0.0.1, it's going to localhost in that log.

I verified, I can login to mysql via terminal myself using the command:

```
$ mysql -u mailadmin -h 127.0.0.1 -p
```

How to get this to work?

**UPDATE:**

This is the output of grants:

[image: Database MySQL User Grants]

Comment: Please provide output of "SHOW GRANTS FOR mailadmin@localost"

Comment: @AndreasRogge The grants are for 'mailadmin'@'127.0.0.1' instead of mailadmin@localhost

Comment: @AndreasRogge My MySQL is a default MariaDB installation, and it is only working with 127.0.0.1 and not localhost.

Comment: just duplicate them for mailadmin@localhost and you're good.

Comment: @AndreasRogge No luck, I'm able to login to mysql via mailadmin@localhost from terminal, but dovecat is still printing the same message.

Comment: @AndreasRogge Added Grants output

Comment: Dovecat is on the same computer with `mysqld`, correct?

Comment: @RickJames Yes, I installed all of them on the same droplet

Comment: Why have you set `host=127.0.0.1` and not the expected `host=localhost`?

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/973454/dovecot-auth-sql-driver-not-respecting-sql-username-options-how-do-i-get-around#comment1266725_973454

Comment: @anx That was exactly the reason. I guess dovecot is treating whatever after the # as a comment and leaving it. Changing the password got it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @anx in the comments, I found the solution to this issue. Creating a new user is not necessary. The problem is that I had a special character in the configuration file.

```
connect = host=127.0.0.1 dbname=servermail user=mailadmin password='pass#12@FQ'
```

When I say like this, dovecot is trying to send the password as `'pass` to the server.

The issue is because of the configuration file format. There is no escape character that I knew for this. So the parser of dovecot is reading the entire line and treating whatever that's coming after the `#` as the comment.

The actual solution was to change the password of the user in MySQL.